# Adding transitions to popup window in javaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Is there any way to adding transition to popup window in javaFX ? (for Popup class)
for example FadeTransition .

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete solution but you can add an event to execute before the window is shown with `.setOnShowing()` and after with `.setOnShown()`

e.g.

```
Popup pop = new Popup();
pop.setOnShowing(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
        //Transition code goes here.
        }
    });
```